# How to get the values(in array format) from a table populated using ngFor on click a button

Tags: angular

I have a simple json using which I populated a table , now on click of button I need to get all the checkbox value and corresponding document id in array format. Here is code below. code demo is here  -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ltme4j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
<h2>Document Types List</h2>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Allow Expired</th>
      <th>Document Types Id</th>
      <th>Document Types Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let documenttype of documenttypes; let i = index">
      <td> <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value={{documenttype.allowexpired}} [checked]="documenttype.allowexpired"> {{documenttype.allowexpired}}</td>
      <td>{{documenttype.docid}}</td>
      <td>{{documenttype.docname}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" #refreshData (click)="submitExpired()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  documenttypes: any[] = [
    {
      allowexpired: true,
      docid: 1,
      docname: 'document1',
    },
    {
      allowexpired: true,
      docid: 2,
      docname: 'document2',
    },
    {
      allowexpired: false,
      docid: 3,
      docname: 'document3',
    },
    {
      allowexpired: false,
      docid: 4,
      docname: 'document4',
    },
  ];
  ngOnInit() {}

  submitExpired() {
    const samplearrayformatValue = [{"allowexpired":true,"docid":1},{"allowexpired":true,"docid":2},{"allowexpired":false,"docid":3},{"allowexpired":false,"docid":4}]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to remove `docname` from the original properties in the new array of objects, you can simply map the array:

```
submitExpired() {
   const newArray = this.documenttypes.map(({ docname, ...item }) => item);
   // console.log(newArray); <- your new array of objects without 'docname' property
}
```

For handling the change of checkbox values, change the (change) parameters in template to: `(change)="getUserSelect(i)"` and in .ts just add:

```
getUserSelect(i) {
   this.documenttypes[i].allowexpired = !this.documenttypes[i].allowexpired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.html**

```html
<button type="submit" #refreshData (click)="submitExpired(documenttypes)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
submitExpired(value) {
   // you have table value here:
const samplearrayformatValue = value;
console.log(JSON.stringify(samplearrayformatValue));
}
```

Comment: It is showing previous value after submit , once I uncheck any checkbox and submit then it should show false value for particular checkbox